# Selenium Python Xpath Text search

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a selenium python web scraper that I inherited and I need to make some changes as the website being scraped changed.

Here is the code that I am making changes to.  The first scenario works, I have it tested.  The second scenario is where I am running into trouble

1. How best could I target the HTML to find the text "Possible Matches"?

my current attempt is using the copy xpath from the line of HTML that has that "Possible Matches" Text.  I have also used the xpath from the 2 HTML lines above that text and no luck.

```
# First Scenario

        if "No patients were found for the requested search criteria" in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="queryResultsForm"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/b').text:
            al= []
        
#Second Scenario

        elif "Possible Matches" in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="queryResultsForm"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/b').text:
 
            driver.find_element_by_id("redirect1").click()
```

HTML at point of failure.

```
<form name="frmWIR" id="queryResultsForm" method="POST" action="!search_ui.matchClient">
<input type="hidden" name="fldSecurid" value="1552531808170227610645991756">
<input type="hidden" name="fldpTarget" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="txtOrgId" value="110113">
<input type="hidden" name="srhCrt" value="N">
<input type="hidden" name="hAction" value="">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="margin-top:7px;">
     <tbody><tr>
       <td width="6">&nbsp;</td>
       <td>
         <table align="left" width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tbody><tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td height="25"><p class="large"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Patient Search Criteria / Results </b></p></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
           <tr>
             <td valign="top">
               <table bgcolor="#f0f0f0" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                 <tbody><tr>
                   <td width="20%" align="right"><b>Last Name</b></td>
                   <td width="15%"><input tabindex="1" maxlength="35" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" value="DOE" size="15" style="HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 140px"></td>
                   <td align="right" width="140">Patient ID</td>
                   <td colspan="2"><input tabindex="13" maxlength="20" id="txtPatientID" name="txtChartNumber" value="" style="HEIGHT: 22px;    WIDTH: 135px"></td>
                   <td align="right"><input name="cmdFindClient" tabindex="-1" style="HEIGHT: 35px; WIDTH: 169px" title="Perform Advanced Search" type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="Search"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right"><b>First Name</b></td>
                   <td><input tabindex="2" maxlength="25" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" value="JOHN" size="15" style="HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 140px"></td>
                   <td align="right">ImmuNet ID</td>
                   <td colspan="2"><input tabindex="14" maxlength="10" id="txtWirID" name="txtWirID" value="" size="10" style="HEIGHT: 22px;    WIDTH: 135px"></td>
                   <td align="right"><input name="cmdFindClient" tabindex="-1" style="HEIGHT: 35px; WIDTH: 169px" title="Return to the previous screen" type="button" onclick="location.href = 'javascript: window.history.go(-1);'" value="Cancel"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">Middle Name</td>
                   <td><input tabindex="3" maxlength="25" id="txtMiddleName" name="txtMiddleName" value="" size="15" style="HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 140px"></td>
                   <td align="right"></td>
                   <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right"><b>Birth Date</b></td>
                     <td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                       <tbody><tr>
                         <td align="left"><input tabindex="3" maxlength="10" size="10" id="txtBirthDate" name="txtBirthDate" value="04/13/2020" style="HEIGHT:  22px; WIDTH: 100px" onkeypress="return formatDate(event,frmWIR.txtBirthDate);" onselect="return selectDate();"></td>
                         <td>&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openCalendar(frmWIR.txtBirthDate)"><img src="/ir_img/calendar_new.gif" border="1"></a></td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                   </td>
                   <td align="right"></td>
                   <td colspan="2"></td>
                   <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                 <tr style="HEIGHT: 37px;">
                   <td width="10%" align="right">Gender</td>
                   <td valign="middle" align="left">
                     <select name="optSexCode" id="optSexCode" size="1" tabindex="7">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="F">Female</option>
                    <option value="M" selected="">Male</option>
                    <option value="U">Unknown</option>
                  </select>
                   </td><td colspan="1"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr style="HEIGHT: 37px;">
                   <td align="right">Phone</td>
                   <td colspan="2">
                     <input tabindex="10" maxlength="3" name="txtareacode" value="" size="3" onkeyup="autoTab(this,3,'frmWIR.txtphone1.focus();')">&nbsp;-
                     <input tabindex="11" maxlength="3" name="txtphone1" value="" size="3" onkeyup="autoTab(this,3,'frmWIR.txtphone2.focus();')">&nbsp;-    
                     <input tabindex="12" maxlength="4" name="txtphone2" value="" size="4">&nbsp; 
                   </td>
                 </tr><tr>
                   <td align="right">Mother's Maiden Last</td>
                   <td><input tabindex="3" maxlength="35" size="15" id="txtMaidenLast" name="txtMaidenLast" value="" style="HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 140px"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right" valign="middle">Mother's First Name</td>
                   <td style="padding-top:8px"><input tabindex="4" maxlength="25" size="15" id="txtMothersFirst" name="txtMothersFirst" value="" style="HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH:    140px"></td>
                 </tr>
                 
               </tbody></table>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody></table>
       </td>
     </tr>
</tbody></table>
<style>
A.sort:link { COLOR:    white; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,SansSerif; FONT-SIZE: 11px; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
A.sort:active { COLOR: white; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,SansSerif; FONT-SIZE:    11px; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
A.sort:hover    { COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,SansSerif; FONT-SIZE: 11px; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
A.sort:visited {    COLOR: white; FONT-FAMILY: Arial,Helvetica,SansSerif; FONT-SIZE: 11px; TEXT-DECORATION: none}
</style>
<!--    START buildQueryResults -->
<table border="0" width="96%" align="center" style="FONT-FAMILY:    Verdana; margin-left:5px;FONT-SIZE: 8pt">
     <tbody><tr>
       <td colspan="9" align="right"><b>Possible Matches: 1 </b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#7c7c7c">
       <td width="14%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Last  Name</b></font></td>
       <td width="12%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>First Name</b></font></td>
       <td width="10%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Middle Name</b></font></td>
       <td width="12%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Birth Date</b></font></td>
       <td width="11%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Patient ID</b></font></td>
       <td width="11%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Mother's Maiden   First</b></font></td>
       <td width="11%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Mother's Maiden   Last</b></font></td>
       <td width="7%" style="border-right:2px solid white" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Gender</b></font></td>
       <td width="12%" class="GridHeading" align="center"><font color="white"><b>Status</b></font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
       <td>
         <a href="wizard_ui.viewClientSchedule?pSecureId=1552531808170227610645991756&amp;pClientId=8378077&amp;pForward=readonly">DOE</a>
       </td>
       <td>JOHN</td>
       <td>DOE</td>
       <td align="center">04/13/2020</td>
       <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
       <td>JANE</td>
       <td>DOE</td>
       <td align="center">M</td>
       <td align="center">N</td>
     </tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" name="txtClientList" value="8378077">
<input type="hidden" name="txtSortField" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="txtSortOrder" value="">
<script language="javascript">
     function redirectURL(url,clientId,i) {
    var Target=3 ;
 var frm=document.forms["frmWIR"]; 
    var secureId=frm.fldSecurid.value;
    var redirectId="redirect"+i;
    mFldOprId = $(".styled-radio:checked").val();
       if(mFldOprId == "PatientImm") {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href="wizard_ui.viewClientSchedule?pSecureId="+secureId+"&pClientId="+clientId; 
     }
      else if(mFldOprId == "PatientDemo") {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"auth/manageClient.do?pSecureId="+secureId+"&clientId="+clientId; 
     }
      else if(mFldOprId == "PatientRepos") {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"viewClientReports.do?pT=2&pSecureId="+secureId+"&pClientId="+clientId; 
     }
      else if(mFldOprId == "BloodLeadHistory") {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"viewBloodLeadHistory.do?pT=2&pSecureId="+secureId+"&pClientId="+clientId; 
     }
     }
     function redirectURLhep(url,clientId,hepBId,infantId,i) {
    var Target=3 ;
 var frm=document.forms["frmWIR"]; 
    var secureId=frm.fldSecurid.value;
    var redirectId="redirect"+i;
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"auth/hepBCaseListing.do?pSecureId="+secureId+"&pT=2&forward=caseListing&clientId="+clientId+"&PerinatalHepbId="+hepBId; 
     }
     function redirectURLInfanthep(url,clientId,hepBId,infantId,i) {
    var Target=3 ;
    var maternalHepBId=-1 ;
 var frm=document.forms["frmWIR"]; 
    var secureId=frm.fldSecurid.value;
    var redirectId="redirect"+i;
       if(maternalHepBId>0 && hepBId == -1 && infantId == -1) {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"hepBInfantCasePage.do?pT=3&pStatus=load&pSecureId="+secureId+"&clientId="+clientId+"&pMaternalCaseId="+maternalHepBId; 
     }
      else {
 document.getElementById(redirectId).href=url+"auth/hepBCaseListing.do?pSecureId="+secureId+"&pT=2&forward=caseListing&clientId="+clientId+"&PerinatalHepbId="+hepBId; 
     }
     }
</script>
<!--    END buildQueryResults -->
</form>
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will edit the post to make that more clear.  Thank you.